# psql variable holding text with multiple lines

Tags: postgresql, psql

This works as expected,

```
\set x '''2\n3'''
```

but this doesn't

```
\set x '''2
3'''
```

Is there a workaround for later example so I don't have to use `\n` instead of newline?

Comment: `psql` commands are oneliners (including `\copy`, being the only one that annoys me regularly).  If you tell us the purpose of this, we might come up with a better idea.

Comment: @dezso I would like to paste some text into psql which can be later used for queries. `\gset` is probably able to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, the `\gset` command should be used for multiline variable content,

```
select '''2
3''' x \gset
```